# About dual of finitely generated projective module

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, projective-module, free-modules

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated projective module, $x \in M$ and $x \neq 0$. Then is it true that there is $g \in M^*$ such that $gx \neq 0$?

If yes how to prove it? For vector space dual this result is true, but what about projective module?

> Also if $f \in M^*$, $f \neq 0$ then $fy \neq 0$ is also true or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes, since finitely generated projective modules are reflexive (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2229893)), meaning that the canonical injective map $M\to M^{**}$ is an isomorphism. Hence if $x\neq 0$, then $x\neq 0\in M^{**}$, so there is $g\in M^*$ such that $gx=\langle g, x\rangle\neq 0$.

I don't know what is $y$ in your second question. If you means there exists such an $y$, then it's true by definition of $f\neq 0$.

Comment: Actually, the assumption that $M$ is finitely generated is redundant.